# JSF inputHelperDatePicker

Tags: jsf, websphere

I have a problem with JSF inputHelperDatePicker. I'm using the following code:

```
 <h:inputText id="text">
   <hx:convertDateTime pattern="dd.mm.yyyy">
   <hx:inputHelperDatePicker id="datePicker"/>
<h:inputText />
```

When I pick inputText, little caledar appears, but there is only current month and year, I can not choose other. Also it can not hitch any styleClass.

Please, if you know how it can be solved or if there is any documentation about it, help me.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context for the view?  Also, here's some documentation that may be helpful: [hx:convertDateTime](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.jsf.doc/topics/rsubhxconvertDateTime.html)

Answer (score 0):

When I was using RAD and drag/dropped the control, I got;

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{pc_XXX.bar}">
    <hx:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    <hx:inputHelperDatePicker />
    <hx:inputHelperAssist errorClass="inputText_Error" />
</h:inputText>
```